# C# databinding combobox to field and populate list from other list

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have these classes:

```
public class City { 
public string name { get; set; } 
public override string ToString() { return name; } 
}
public List<City> cities = new List();
public class Person {
public string name { get; set; }
public string addr { get; set; }
public City city { get; set; }
}
List<Person> persons;
```

I bind cities and persons to `bindingSource` (and to list and textbox):

```
bindingSource_city.DataSource = cities;
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource_city, "name");
bindingSource_person.DataSource = person;
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource_person, "name");
textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource_person, "addr");
```

also `listBox.DataSource = bindingSource` (in form editor).

All seems to work fine.
How can I create combobox with cities in list and binded to person.city property?
I cant understand how to fill drop-down list with objects (not string items).

EDIT: Or how to convert person.city to `SelectedIndex` on data (list index) change and back.

Comment: Thank, but its not an answer. In you example combobox binded to one bindingSource and in my - to two.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to do:

```
comboBoxCities.DataSource = bindingSource1;
comboBoxCities.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Comment: How its binded to person.city? I can fill drop-down list, but i cant understand how to bind it to property.

Comment: I try to manually update data in list, and its works fine.
Also I try to use you code. It has side effect - when i change cursor (SelectedIndex) in comboBox, cursor in first listBox also changed :)

Answer (score -1):

Partially solved by adding events:

```
bindingSouce_city_ListChanges
{
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach( City c in cities ) comboBox1.Items.Add( c );
}
comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(...)
{
int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
((Person) bindigSource_person).city = (i < ? null: cities[ i ]);
}
bindingSource_person_CurrentChanged(...)
{
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 
cities.IndexOf( ((Person) bindingSource_person).city );
}
```

Its not very nice code, I think, but its work.

UPD: Thanks to [eugene-podskal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3745022/eugene-podskal)
Solution is:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = bindinsSource_city;
comboBox1.DataBinding.Add( "SelectedItem", bindingSource_person, "city" );
```

Comment: Have you tried just to add a binding on SelectedItem to your person's city? Like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343543/winforms-binding-a-combobox-selecteditem-to-an-object-property?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Its what I want!

Comment: Do I need to update my answer or question for proper solution?

Comment: Answers are for answers, questions are for questions, so you should update the answer. Just make a more specific title for your question (the current one doesn't fully describe the issue - I'd recommend something along the line of 'Binding ComboBox's DataSource to one object and SelectedItem to another '), and add `[winforms]` [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to it.